# asp.net api error - return ambiguousMatchException or page not found

Tags: asp.net

i have an problem with call to api, i get ambiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints 
or page not found.

this happen after i add testApi to my controller, before all works good.
why it's happen and how to fix it? i want to add more function to this controller.

thank's!!!!!!

my code:

```
namespace AutomationTool.Api
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestCasesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public TestCasesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id:int}")] -- > here the problem
        public int testApi(int id)
        {
            return 1;
        }


        // GET: api/TestCases
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<TestCase>>> GetTestCases()
        {
            return await _context.TestCases.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/TestCases/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TestCase>> GetTestCase(int id)
        {
            var testCase = await _context.TestCases.FindAsync(id);

            if (testCase == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return testCase;
        }   
    }
}
```